# PowerShell and VB6 COM+ modules: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: powershell, com, vb6

I´m trying to use powershell to do automatic tests in my system, but 30% of this system is VB6 modules used thru COM. Some os these modules uses private variables that are globals inside the module. With VB6 functions that don´t use these variables, everything works fine, but with the functions that rely on these "private globals", I´m getting the error "Object variable or With block variable not set". Unfortunately, migrate this VB6 code will not occur in short term.

This is a piece of this legacy code:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
  Persistable = 0  'NotPersistable
  DataBindingBehavior = 0  'vbNone
  DataSourceBehavior  = 0  'vbNone
  MTSTransactionMode  = 1  'NoTransaction
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Data"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Attribute VB_Ext_KEY = "SavedWithClassBuilder6" ,"Yes"
Attribute VB_Ext_KEY = "Top_Level" ,"Yes"
Option Explicit

Private oConn        As ADODB.Connection
Private oRs          As ADODB.Recordset

Public Function rsOperadora(ByVal sUser As String, _
                             ByVal sPassword As String, _
                             ByVal sIP As String, _
                             ByVal sSystem As String, _
                             ByVal sModule As String)


    Dim sSql As String

    sSql = "select * from operator"


    Call Connect(sUser, sPassword, sSystem, sModule, sIP)

    oRs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    oRs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    oRs.Open sSql, oConn, , adLockBatchOptimistic
    oRs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    Set rsOperadora = oRs

    Set oConn = Nothing

End Function
```

What I tried to do:

```
PS E:\aazevedo> $tsdb = New-Object -ComObject "TSDB.Data"
PS E:\aazevedo> $tsdb.rsOperadora

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Variant rsOperadora (string, string, string, string, string)



PS E:\aazevedo> $tsdb.rsOperadora("ADMIN","8482867D8B958F0E","","DESENV11","")
Exception calling "rsOperadora" with "5" argument(s): "Object variable or With block variable not set"
At line:1 char:1
+ $tsdb.rsOperadora("ADMIN","8482867D8B958F0E","","DESENV11","")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

PS E:\aazevedo> $oRs = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
PS E:\aazevedo> $tsdb.rsOperadora("ADMIN","8482867D8B958F0E","","DESENV11","")
Exception calling "rsOperadora" with "5" argument(s): "Object variable or With block variable not set"
At line:1 char:1
+ $tsdb.rsOperadora("ADMIN","8482867D8B958F0E","","DESENV11","")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

PS E:\aazevedo> oRs = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
oRs : The term 'oRs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ oRs = New-Object -ComObject "ADODB.Recordset"
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (oRs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

In this example, the function Connect open a database connection using ADO, assigning to the variable oConn.

I think my problem is the variable oRs.

Inside ASP Classic this module works.

PS: sorry for my poor english.

Comment: oRs isn't set in your code - is it initialised anywhere? If not then it will produce that error.

Comment: set oRs = new ADODB.Recordset is what you are looking for

Comment: I don't see any place that you are setting your oRs powershell variable to the oRs variable in your object, which you need to do.  What's more, you can't do it with a Private variable AFAIK (I don't know much about powershell).